# Extendscript dropdownlist item color

Tags: extendscript, adobe-scriptui

Does anyone know if you can change the color of the text for specific items in a dropdown list in Adobe's extendscript ScriptUI? I know about the color section of the Script UI guide, however that says nothing about list items and I tried a few things by chance but wasn't able to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The ScriptUI is converted to HTML5/CSS behind the scenes. Because the CSS is not exposed to the user, it is not possible to change any of the colour schemes.

You can use images for buttons to add colour to them, but that wouldn't apply to dropdowns.

I'm not certain about the other Adobe programs, but I know that creating an extension (as opposed to a script) for After Effects is a way of circumventing this restriction.

Comment: Thanks Clif. Man script UI is total garbage when compared to modern GUI frameworks... I've also been banging my head against CEP panels to circumvent these archaic restrictions, but unfortunately Adobe's implementation of CEP is also... frankly limited. I posted up a feature request for python a few years ago on the user voice forum and was surprised to get almost no upvotes. Sad...